# tester.scrollUntilVisible() not working with GridView in flutter integration testing

Tags: flutter, gridview, integration-testing

I am trying to scroll and find widget from the GridView in `integration testing` in flutter. But the code not working:

```
tester.scrollUntilVisible(itemFinder, -100, scrollable: gridViewFinder)
```

But this is not working. It is saying GridView is not scrollable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are few steps I made mistake here:

1. `scrollUntilVisible`() is `Future`, so

   await tester.scrollUntilVisible(...);
2. to scroll down, delta should be positive:

   await tester.scrollUntilVisible(itemFinder, 100.0, ...);
3. if there is only one list in screen, I don't have to include scrollable:

   await tester.scrollUntilVisible(itemFinder, 100.0);

Now done!
**Final answer:**

```
 await tester.scrollUntilVisible(itemFinder, 100.0);
```